# Is it possible to merge java\jre\security\lib\cacerts file

Tags: java, authentication, tomcat, spring-mvc, cas

In my project,I have integrated Spring Security with CAS server authentication. Now my project is an http application where as the CAS server is an Https application. I was getting following exception after Spring Security and CAS integration: `sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`

In order to solve this error ,I replaced CAS server usr\java\jre\lib\security\cacerts file with my local usr\java\jre\lib\security\cacerts file. After this step the error was gone.

Now I want to deploy my application to some other server. In this new server some other applications are also deployed which may be using different CAS authentication. I cannot directly replace my CAS server cacerts file with this new server cacerts file as in that other application deployed may fail.Right? Can anyone suggest what should I do so that cacerts can be merged,or what should be done? i got to know a command called as keytool but unable to understand how it could be used to merge cacerts file. I dont know how to get my CAS server .cer file,I got to know this could be used in merging,please suggest solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a missunderstanding here.
`cacerts` is Java's default truststore containing all the trusted certificates for known CA's (Verisign etc). So java can by default trust these certificates same way that your browser does.

This truststore should be used when you want to connect to servers that are signed by these CAs.
In all other cases you are expected to use your own custom truststore so that you can trust specific servers.Actually this is the norm.

So what you should be doing is to load in your code ***your own truststore*** and provide that to Java's JSSE to use for authentication during handshake

Comment: Ok..but how to do this? How to get certificate and add to trust store? any idea?

Comment: If you already have the truststore then you could set it via `System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStrore", "myTrustStore.p12");`?

Comment: No I dont have trust store? The System.setProperty command is to be used in java code right? Cant we do it through KeyTool ?Ex. keytool -import -alias joe -file jcertfile.cer ;Please let me know how to create trust store and export the certificate from CAS server and finally import the certificate into new server?

Comment: You can use keytool, but the idea is to create a new keystore file containing your certificate, and use that keystore file as the new truststore (via the `System` properties).Do you understand?